# Check if record exist in Google sheet before import from SQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a Google sheet, with data imported from MySQL database. So I have a script that get the data and put into my sheet. The data is from a website, which record subscriptions for members.

That I search for, is to update my Google sheet with new data in my database. I want if I trigger the function, that put new data under the existing data in my Google sheet.

All I can do actually, is overwrite the data in my sheet from database. Is there a way to check in my database (on my website) if data is already exist in my Googlesheet before importing ?

I am not a programmer, but I try to auto-learn, So it is difficult for me.

Here is the code I use actually in the app script in Google sheet :

```
function RecupDataMP_deco_fascicules() { 
  
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:mysql://NAME_OF_MY_DATABASE', 'USER', 'PASSWORD'); 

  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var start = new Date(); // Get script starting time
  
  var rs = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT tgze_osmembership_field_value.field_id, tgze_osmembership_field_value.field_value, tgze_osmembership_field_value.subscriber_id, tgze_osmembership_subscribers.plan_id, tgze_osmembership_subscribers.last_name, tgze_osmembership_subscribers.country, tgze_osmembership_subscribers.created_date, tgze_osmembership_subscribers.payment_date, tgze_osmembership_subscribers.gross_amount, tgze_osmembership_subscribers.payment_method, tgze_osmembership_subscribers.plan_subscription_status, tgze_osmembership_subscribers.email, tgze_osmembership_plans.title FROM tgze_osmembership_subscribers LEFT JOIN tgze_osmembership_field_value ON tgze_osmembership_subscribers.id = tgze_osmembership_field_value.subscriber_id LEFT JOIN tgze_osmembership_plans ON tgze_osmembership_subscribers.plan_id = tgze_osmembership_plans.id WHERE (tgze_osmembership_field_value.field_id = "118" AND tgze_osmembership_field_value.field_value = "Oui, avec fascicules papier (+50.- EUR)") OR (tgze_osmembership_field_value.field_id = "110" AND tgze_osmembership_field_value.field_value = "Oui, avec fascicules papier (+40.- CHF)") ORDER BY tgze_osmembership_subscribers.payment_date DESC LIMIT 30'); 
  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var doc = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]; 
  var cell = doc.getRange('a1'); 
  var row = 0; 
  var getCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < getCount; i++){  
     cell.offset(row, i).setValue(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1)); 
  }  
  
  var row = 1; 
  while (rs.next()) {
    for (var col = 0; col < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); col++) { 
      cell.offset(row, col).setValue(rs.getString(col + 1)); 
    }
    row++;
  }
  
  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
  var end = new Date(); // Get script ending time
  Logger.log('Time elapsed: ' + (end.getTime() - start.getTime())); 
}
```

But each time I use it, it replace the existing data.

I see the NOT EXISTS function, but I don't know if that is what I need, and how use that not between 2 SQL tables, but between my SQL table and my sheet.